# Should I <CFLOCK> a <CFFILE Action="COPY" ...>?

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9

Looking over some old code that timeouts occasionally, I came across this CFLOCK around a CFFILE COPY run inside a CFLOOP.

Does this use of CFFLOCK make sense or seem necessary? The file is being copied from one location to a newly created folder that is itself then zipped up for a future download.

At first, I was just going to increase the timeout of the lock but then I started to stare at it and wonder if it was a mistake.

```
<cfloop query="LOCAL.qDocsZip">
<cflock name="copyFileLock" timeout="3600" type="readonly">
<cffile action="copy"
source="#ExpandPath(LOCAL.qDocsZip.file_location)#"     
destination="#LOCAL.zip_new_path#/#LOCAL.qDocsZip.original_file_name#">
</cflock>
</cfloop>
```

Comment: First question I would ask is, what is the lock supposed to be doing? Basic locking of concurrent read/write of files is usually handled by the o/s well enough, so what is the code doing beyond that, that requires extra locking (and is the single name "copyFileLock" granular enough for that purpose)? Also, I noticed "zip" in the file name. If this locking involves zipping files, there might be a better approach like generating a uniquely named temp file or folder, which shouldn't require any locking.

Comment: A zip file is being created for later download by a end user.  This code is from a block that, after receiving a list of files that exist on a file server from a user, creates new folder, copies the files on the list to that folder, and then zips that folder, saving the path of the new folder to a database. The main idea behind the cflock had to do with the remote chance that same file might be copied at the same time by two different users to two different folders. But It seems to me that is a misunderstanding of when to use cflock.

Comment: Hm... usually dynamic downloads are a one time thing, so there's no conflict with other threads or need for locking.  What is it about this particular "copy" action that requires locking from other threads? Because that lock single threads the copy for ANY thread that hits that code block - not just ones accessing the same file or folder.  Also, is the zip file ultimately deleted once it's downloaded?

Comment: (Didn't see your edit)  *But It seems to me that is a misunderstanding of when to use cflock* Possibly, unless maybe the files being copied are volatile and could be altered by other threads at the same time? However, even if that were the case, you shouldn't need such such a broad lock.  The way the code is written blocks ANY thread from copying a file, not just the current file being copied.  That's probably why you're getting occasional time outs.

Answer (score 2):

Locking seems reasonable here, but it's not the right spot and you are not locking the file access exlusively. You should lock the whole transaction, i.e. lock right before you fetch `LOCAL.qDocsZip`. This way you are making sure that the files to copy are only touched by a single thread and do not run into concurrency with another thread. On that note: `cflock` is a JVM specific semaphore, so it cannot guarantee transaction safety on a system level, e.g. if you have other programs that access your files parallel.

Here is what it should look like:

```
<!--- only one thread at a time can execute the code within this lock (exclusive named lock) --->
<cflock name="copyFileLock" timeout="3600" type="exclusive">

    <!--- fetch files to copy in this transaction --->
    <cfquery name="LOCAL.qDocsZip" ...>
        ...
    </cfquery>

    <!--- copy all the files --->
    <cfloop query="LOCAL.qDocsZip">
        <cffile action="copy" ...>
    </cfloop>

</cflock>
```

(You should probably add some error handling as well, if that's not just left out in your snippet.)

## Explanation

Every thread will stop at `cflock` and ask the semaphore `copyFileLock` if it is currently "running". If not, the thread will continue, fetch the files and copy them. While this whole copying is in progress (the semaphore is "running"), every other thread that encounters the `cflock` will be queued, so pause the execution and wait for the semaphore (in your case, every queued thread will wait 3600 seconds for the semaphore to give the "go", or otherwise just forget about it and exit). After the copy operation has finished on the first thread, the semaphore will stop "running" and check the queue. If other threads were queued in the meantime, the next thread in queue will resume execution, rinse and repeat.

The exclusive lock will make sure, that a thread never "sees" an incomplete file state (= fetch a file that is about to be copied by another thread).

Comment: That's a good explanation. However, without knowing more about the overall process (and whether variable names involving "zip" is just coincidental) I would still question whether or not locking is necessary and/or the use of such a broad lock name is appropriate.